# PHP communicates with Node.js (Socket.io) running besides Apache

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, apache, socket.io

Is it possible that PHP to communicate with Node.js server in order to mimic real-time web apps developed completely in PHP+Apache+MySQL?

My thinking is this:

Two users, John and Adam, are viewing the same page where you can write comments.

1. John writes a comment and hits submit.
2. The comment is POSTed to PHP
3. PHP saves the message in a database and Memcached
4. PHP communicates with Node.js to update the comments page
5. Node.js opens a socket (or other transport method with Socket.io) and updates the comments page in the browser.
6. Adam sees a new comment added on the page in 'real-time'

I want to do this because it's much easier for me to work with PHP instead of handling all server-side stuff with node.js. And I don't want to change my whole world of PHP app to Node.js. Any good code example? or article?

Comment: You can just call node like any other program with `exec('node test.js');` - which bit of your question are you struggling with?

Comment: you might want to review your approach, i see steps 2-3-4-5 being wrong for many reasons, try reading socket.io wiki on what websockets are.

Comment: What are you using Node.js for? If it is for a specific part of your site (e.g. chat) could you use Node there, and PHP everywhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend [dnode-php](https://github.com/bergie/dnode-php) to accomplish this.
Dnode is an asynchronous rpc system for node.js that lets you call remote functions and dnode-php is the php implementation.

Comment: This is quite a similar to what I was looking for but I cannot understand of working with it. Can you provide some short code so I can understand better

Comment: @JohnSmith Here is an little [tutorial](http://bergie.iki.fi/blog/dnode-make_php_and_node-js_talk_to_each_other/)